# linq mvc foreign key value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, foreign-keys

I am new to MVC. and I'm trying to find my way through online tutorials.

being said that,

I have a table A (a1,a2,a_b1)
and a table B (b1,b2)

and a_b1 is a foreign key from B.b1.

I generated the List view in Visual studio, using its template.
I have access to a1, and a2 fields of table A.
    `<%=Html.Encode(item.a1) %>`  and `<%=Html.Encode(item.a2) %>`

but when I try to access the A.a_b1 value (NOT the reference to table B), I only get the reference to an object from table B.
Thanks Kirill 
I don't know what are  CodeFirst, ModelFirst or DatabaseFirst.
I have these tables, and used visual studio, and Linq to generate the class for tables A and B.
so A.a1, A.a2 show up in the object created.
and I have A.B, and A.BReference in the fields

I think there should be a way to access the value of the column not the reference. 
Can you please help me?

I don't want to perform the join, just need the value.

I tried my best to be specific but please let me know if this is not clear.

Thanks

EDIT:

I used ADO.Net Entity Data Model to generate objects associated with my tables.

In my controller I have :

```
A sample1=repository.search(id);
string s1 = sample1.a1;
string s2 = sample1.a2;
string s3 = sample1.a_b1; (ERROR)
```

Instead I have

```
   sample1.B   (an object of type B)
and 
sample1.BReference  (object of type EntityReference<B>)
```

Comment: Try accessing via "sample1.a_b1.b1" or "sample1.a_b1.b2"

Comment: Thanks, When I do that, I get a null pointer exception in my View. I think I need to load the a_b1 object, but I don't know how to send it to view. (I'm very new at MVC)

Comment: initialize the a_b1 object in controller and send it to view i.e. "sample1.a_b1 = new b();"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for those who ran into the same problem:

I defined a new class A_text that has all the fields of A. (including a_b1)

and in Select, I used :

```
var result = from pt in db.A
                     where pt.id== id
                     select new A_text
                     {
                         id= pt.id,
                         a1= pt.a1,
                         a2 = pt.a2,
                         a_b1= pt.a_b1.id
                     };
        return (result.FirstOrDefault());
```

I'm not sure about the efficiency compared to the

```
 db.Search(id);
```

but seems ok so far.